# How to save parent with children?

Tags: java, hibernate, parent-child, one-to-many, cascade

I have parent entity `Order` with child entity `OrderItem`. I want to save object `Order` together with `Set<OrderItem>`, but `idOrder` is auto increment. Between `Order` and `OrderItem` is **one-to-many** relationship. `OrderItem` include reference to parent `Order`. So `Order` item must be saved firstly and then must be saved `OrderItem` with assigned `idOrder`.

Here is **Order.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="hibernate.Order" table="order" catalog="my">
    <id name="idOrder" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id_order" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <set name="orderItems" inverse="true" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="id_order" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="hibernate.OrderItem" />
    </set>
</class>
```

class **Order**

```
public class Order  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Integer idOrder;
     private Set<OrderItem> orderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>(0);

}
```

Here is **OrderItem.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="hibernate.OrderItem" table="order_item" catalog="my">
    <id name="idOrderItem" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id_order_item" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="order" class="hibernate.Order" fetch="select">
        <column name="id_order" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

class **OrderItem**

```
public class OrderItem  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Integer idOrderItem;
     private Order order;

}
```

When I try save it, it throw me exception.

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: hibernate.Order
```

**EDIT:**
It works with following statement. Is this correct?

```
Order order = mapper.map(dtoOrder, Order.class);

Set<OrderItem> orderItems = order.getOrderItems();
for (OrderItem orderItem : orderItems) {
    orderItem.setOrder(order);
}
order.setOrderItems(orderItems);

session.save(order);
```

Comment: could you attache the code which has saving logic. Maybe a DAO class?
From exception, it seems you are trying to persist an OrderItem before Order instance is persistent.

Comment: yes, since your cascade is actually in ** Order.hbm.xml**, saving an Order will make related OrderItem instance persistent as well, but not the other way around.

Comment: so basically there are 3 workarounds here. 1.Save Order rather than OrderItem, because regarding to your current hibernate configuration the cascading navigates from Order to OrderItem; 2.have a **cascade=save-update** in **OrderItem.hbm.xml** , and then saving an OrderItem will automatically save Order; but this is **not recommented** ; 3. for some reason,if you insist to save OrderItem and don't want to change your hibernate confiuraion, I'm afraid you have to explicitly save Order first and then invoke session.flush() to get Order instance persistent before saving OrderItem.

Comment: Yes, it's clearer after your answer. Thank you!

Comment: ...and please send your comment as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so basically there are 3 workarounds here.

1.Save Order rather than OrderItem, because regarding to your current hibernate configuration the cascading navigates from Order to OrderItem;

2.have a cascade=save-update in OrderItem.hbm.xml , and then saving an OrderItem will automatically save Order; but this is not recommented ;

3.for some reason,if you insist to save OrderItem and don't want to change your hibernate confiuraion, I'm afraid you have to explicitly save Order first and then invoke session.flush() to get Order instance persistent before saving OrderItem;

I hope this make sense.